# Get months from datefield in django

Tags: django, datefield

If I have a Datefield in django model, how can I get all possible months values from model objects?
so if I have object1 with date = 22.01.2013 and object2 with date = 23.05.2013, I need to get list of months [01, 05] or [1, 5]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
months = [i.month for i in MyModel.objects.values_list('date', flat=True)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey I think the dates function is what you are looking for:

Try:

```
month_list = Model.objects.dates('DateField', 'month')
```

Comment: It should be `Model.objects.dates`, and this will return a qs that evaluates to a list of python date objects rather than the month numbers.  But this is a better way to do it than the accepted answer, which is less efficient and will include duplicates.  It is of course easy to get the month numbers from the date objects.

Comment: Oh thanks, forget about the objects attribute. Edited in Answer :)